# Main product images lost while updating images cache in magento

Tags: magento, caching

I flushed catalog images cache from magento cache storage management . Now I have lost all product main images. Image thumbnails are there but i don't see main image for any of the product. 
Any one else faced the same issue ?

Comment: Magento cache storage management didn't remove main product images. It's only clear cache images. are you using any extension  which is related to cache?

Comment: no not using any extension . It has recreated cache folder again inside media/catalog/product/ folder . I was checking another magento and i realised there is folder name 315x inside cache folder which is not created in my case . Is this has something to do with it ?

Comment: in your another magento you are resizing the image with 315x  somewhere in phtml files for product image. That's why that folder created there.